# What type of Radiation hits Europa

Tags: space, radiation

I was recently reading the [Wikipedia Page for Europa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europa_%28moon%29#Surface_features) as I am interested in terra-formation. In one of the sentences, it says that:

> The radiation level at the surface of Europa is equivalent to a dose of about 5400mSv (540 rem) per day,[32] an amount of radiation that would cause severe illness or death in human beings exposed for a single day.[33]

I know that there are different types of radiation (gamma rays, visible light, infrared, etc.) and was wondering, *what is the makeup of the radiation which hits Europa?*

Answer (score 2):

The Wikipedia page to which you linked actually has *citations* which, if followed, would give you the exact information you seek:

(from http://zimmer.csufresno.edu/~fringwal/w08a.jup.txt):

> Effects of radiation, from solar flares:
>
> - Makes aurorae (air glows, like fluorescent lamps)
> - Health danger to astronauts
> - Ages spacecraft electronics (2 satellites failed after 1989 March flare)
> - Charges up spacecraft, causes electical problems
> - Charges up high-voltage power lines, caused Hydro Quebec blackout (1989)
>
> Types of radiation:
>
> - charged particles (protons, electrons, alpha particles (helium nuclei)
> - neutrons
> - ionizing electromagnetic radiation: gamma rays and X-rays
>
> All so energetic, they ionize matter, e.g. your cell membranes.